# SKLabelNode extremely blurry [screenshot included]

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, arkit

I'm trying to add a label to an ARKit project, but it's rendering extremely blurry. See image below:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
shapeNode.name = "bar"
shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.white

let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Hello world")
labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .left
labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .top
labelNode.fontColor = UIColor.black
labelNode.fontSize = 3
```

Comment: Why is your fontSize 3?

Comment: It's the display size that I need.

Comment: What do you think is going to happen with such a tiny font?

Comment: In ARkit its actually about 4 inches wide. Even if I set it to say 12, it's way larger than I need and it's still quite blurry.

Comment: I do not think you understand how it works, you are using SpriteKit not SceneKit, it behaves a little differently.  You are dealing with 2D space.  Ill create a 2D example and see if I get a blurry result

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand to what you're alluding. For my purposes I need to generate text on a 2D surface in 3D space. I tried SCNText and the result was far more pixelated.

Comment: Wait, what?  You are using SKSpriteKit inside of SKScene kit?

Comment: I just finished the demo, text works fine, you are just using too small of a font to be rendered.  You need to figure out what the conversion is from SpriteKit to SceneKit.  In SKSpriteKit, 1 meter is 150 points. So font 15, the word Hello is about 8 inches wide if it was slapped up right next to the camera.  Now I would like to think that apple stuck to this when converting the SKLabel over to scene kit, but I do not know too much about what goes between the 2 kits.

Comment: Ah, okay thanks. I'll keep digging and see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a SKScene for display, you have to give it a size. This is the resolution of what will be rendered. It will then be scaled to the SKSceneView it appears in, according to how you set its scaleMode property. If the resolution of your SKScene is lower than the point size of the view it appears in, the output will be adjusted to fit using a standard scaling algorithm and will therefore be blurry.

Try increasing the size of your SKScene by a little bit and see if that helps. Note that you will likely also have to adjust the size and position of your nodes as these will appear to shrink as the scene gets larger.